# Unicode characters in Jekyll category

Tags: ruby, unicode, jekyll

I'm new to Jekyll and Ruby. I am using it for writing a blog in Polish, which uses non-ASCII characters.

I'd like to use UTF characters in category names - for example, "Świat". Sadly, this leads to the blog post being put in a directory also called "Świat" (with the non-ascii 'Ś' in the name), and the server I am using apparently cannot cope with non-ASCII characters in the URL (I thought non-ascii is not really allowed in URL anyway).

All Polish characters are 'downgradable' to a regular Latin character for the permalink (e.g. 'Ś'->'S'), which seems like the most desirable option here. Is that possible to do automatically somehow? I guess one option would be to manually specify the permalink in the front matter for each post, but that seems cumbersome.

I am using Jekyll 3.2.1, and a template called '[centrarium](https://github.com/bencentra/centrarium)' in case that matters.

Apologies if that's a noob question, I tried googling around but couldn't really find anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit :**

There is no reason for your server to mess with file or folder names containing accented characters. "Świat" is a valid string for any file system.

And Jekyll's url are well encoded, so, using accented chars in url is fine out of the box.

I've tested it [here](https://statiktest.github.io/polishtest/dummy/%C5%9Awiat/2015/04/18/dummy.html), just by adding "Świat" as a category to a post. And it works just fine.

Do you have something visible in a repository ?

**# End edit**

**Old answer :**

This can be done with a [plugin](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks).

But this implies that you can't use github-pages to generate your site. You will have to generate locally and push to your publishing branch (usually gh-pages), or use some Continuous Integration service like Travis.

Comment: Thank you David for the suggestion. I cannot see a plugin that does that already - so I guess I need to write my own one. Do you have any hints? I guess it needs to hook after a post is generated and edit the post's permalink - is that right?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Well, it worked fine locally via `jekyll serve`, but then not on the server. I guess it s an issue with the host; I'll try on another one - thanks!